# How to search a column of prices in a DataFrame based on column from another DataFrame with a date range

Tags: python, dataframe

I  have a DataFrame named data with the dates and prices of each laptop.

```
              Acer      Mac   Toshiba

date                                                                          
2019-01-04  754.23  1173.08    969.15  
2019-01-05  753.69  1176.14    969.42  
2019-01-11  754.21  1171.56    970.30  
2019-01-28  752.61  1153.29    964.96  
2019-01-29  753.43  1148.72    964.43  

2019-02-03  754.27  1157.23    966.60  
2019-02-04  752.97  1150.68    964.72  
2019-02-09  753.25  1152.49    965.20  
2019-02-19  754.25  1154.49    963.20  
2019-02-26  752.25  1155.49    962.20

2019-03-01  753.48  1153.13    966.18  
2019-03-30  753.49  1156.94    966.96
```

I have another DataFrame named laptop with the start & end dates

```
                 start         end     Laptop

2019-01-29  2010-01-04  2010-01-29       Acer
2019-02-26  2010-02-03  2010-02-26    Toshiba
2019-03-30  2019-03-01  2019-03-30        Mac
```

How to I print the prices of the Laptop stated in the 2nd DataFrame within the date range such that it looks like this:

```
              Laptop    Price   

date                                                                          
2019-01-04      Acer    754.23  
2019-01-05      Acer    753.69  
2019-01-11      Acer    754.21  
2019-01-28      Acer    752.61  
2019-01-29      Acer    753.43  

2019-02-03   Toshiba    966.60  
2019-02-04   Toshiba    964.72  
2019-02-09   Toshiba    965.20  
2019-02-19   Toshiba    963.20  
2019-02-26   Toshiba    962.20

2019-03-01       Mac   1153.13    
2019-03-30       Mac   1156.94
```

The following is what I have but it doesn't print the prices:

```
for date in data.index:
    for date1 in laptop['end']:
        if date == date1:
            start = laptop['start']
            end = laptop['end']
            laptop = laptop['Laptop']
    p = data.loc[start: end, laptop]    #to search for the prices for the laptop chosen in the respective date range 

print(p)
```

I get the following error:

ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [labels (MUST BE IN THE INDEX), slices of labels (BOTH endpoints included! Can be slices of integers if the index is integers), listlike of labels, boolean] types

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the dates of the `laptop` are bad since the year is 2010 in some. I have changed it to 2019 to get the results that are required

laptop is:

```
                 start         end     Laptop

2019-01-29  2019-01-04  2019-01-29       Acer
2019-02-26  2019-02-03  2019-02-26    Toshiba
2019-03-30  2019-03-01  2019-03-30        Mac
```

**You can use:**

```
lst=[]
i=0
while i<len(laptop.index):
    data['Laptop']=laptop.loc[laptop.index[i],'Laptop']
    lst.append((data.loc[(laptop.loc[laptop.index[i],'start']<=data.index) & (laptop.loc[laptop.index[i],'end']>=data.index)][['Laptop',data['Laptop'][0]]].rename(columns={data['Laptop'][0]:'Prices'})))
    print(lst[i])
    print('-'*50)
    i+=1

new_df=pd.concat([df for df in lst])
data=data.drop(['Laptop'], axis=1)
print(new_df)
```

**Output:**

```
             Laptop  Prices
date                     
2019-01-04   Acer    754.23
2019-01-05   Acer    753.69
2019-01-11   Acer    754.21
2019-01-28   Acer    752.61
2019-01-29   Acer    753.43
--------------------------------------------------
             Laptop  Prices
date                       
2019-02-03  Toshiba  966.60
2019-02-04  Toshiba  964.72
2019-02-09  Toshiba  965.20
2019-02-19  Toshiba  963.20
2019-02-26  Toshiba  962.20
--------------------------------------------------
             Laptop  Prices
date                      
2019-03-01    Mac    1153.13
2019-03-30    Mac    1156.94
--------------------------------------------------
             Laptop   Prices
date                        
2019-01-04     Acer   754.23
2019-01-05     Acer   753.69
2019-01-11     Acer   754.21
2019-01-28     Acer   752.61
2019-01-29     Acer   753.43
2019-02-03  Toshiba   966.60
2019-02-04  Toshiba   964.72
2019-02-09  Toshiba   965.20
2019-02-19  Toshiba   963.20
2019-02-26  Toshiba   962.20
2019-03-01      Mac  1153.13
2019-03-30      Mac  1156.94
```

I have concatenated the `DataFrame` for each `laptop` you can leave without concatenating

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. Please explain this part of code: "    lst.append((df.loc[(df2.loc[df2.index[i],'start']<=df.index) & (df2.loc[df2.index[i],'end']>=df.index)][['Laptop',df['Laptop'][0]]].rename(columns={df['Laptop'][0]:'Prices'})))".  I get the first part is to check for the date range. How about the 2nd portion?

Comment: I also got this error: <IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices> for this line of code

Comment: sorry for using `df` and `df2` instead of `data` and `laptop`, I have already updated this correctly

Comment: in the line for which you have asked me, a dataframe is created for each laptop from the data column, the price columns that are not needed in each case are deleted and the time range is selected

Comment: Note that to use your DataFrame I have used `pd.read_clipboard()`, it may have changed the type of some column or index and therefore the code throws some error

Comment: I just checked that having the index as datetime does not affect the validity of the code.

Comment: the second part of the line you asked me for eliminates the price columns that are not needed. Prices are also set as the column name

Comment: Thank you so much. I have gotten the output as expected.